# Detect tap in Samsung Gear VR

Tags: c#, input, oculus, unity-game-engine

how can I detect tap in Gear Vr to make an action

I use unity 5 with C# programming language

my tries

I read answers in untiy3d forums

none of them work to me

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/samsung-gear-vr-detect-tap-swipe.298346/

any suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to implement the tap, (or in reality a click, as the touchpad works as a mouse) yourself. A tap is a touch/mouse down, and then a touch/mouse up in a relatively same place.

Here's some untested code that should work (call if it doesn't):

```
using UnityEngine;
public class ClickDetector:MonoBehaviour {

    public int button=0;
    public float clickSize=50; // this might be too small

    void ClickHappened() {
        Debug.Log("CLICK!");
    }

    Vector3 pos;
    void Update() {
      if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(button))
        pos=Input.mousePosition;

      if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(button)) {
        var delta=Input.mousePosition-pos;
        if(delta.sqrMagnitude < clickSize*clickSize)
          ClickHappened();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Where is this script attached?

Comment: Wherever you want, for example to the Main Camera.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @chanibal I find answer

```
Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)
```

but I face another problem , application crush

is there any custom configuration to Gear VR

Comment: Note that `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` does not distinguish a tap from a swipe. And for the crash, well, you have to provide way more info than this (do this in a separate question).